# EF Core declaring multiple variables on complex Where Clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this LINQ `Where` clause that is declaring 2 variables on the SQL query

```
var parkingLotPrice = 
                _context.ParkingLotPrice
                    .Where(x => currentDate >= x.EffectiveDate && (currentDate <= x.ExpiryDate || x.ExpiryDate == null))
                    .ToQueryString();
```

It generates this SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @__currentDate_0 datetime2 = '2021-07-21T17:48:29.1106534-06:00';
DECLARE @__currentDate_1 datetime2 = '2021-07-21T17:48:29.1106534-06:00';

SELECT  [p].[ParkingLotId], 
        [p].[PriceScheduleId],
        [p].[EffectiveDate], 
        [p].[ExpiryDate]
FROM [ParkingLotPrice] AS [p]
WHERE (@__currentDate_0 >= [p].[EffectiveDate]) AND ((@__currentDate_1 <= [p].[ExpiryDate]) OR [p].[ExpiryDate] IS NULL)
```

Note: the declarations contains the same value.

The problem is the `(currentDate <= x.ExpiryDate || x.ExpiryDate == null)`.

If I remove the `null` evaluation, it only declares 1 variable.

```
DECLARE @__currentDate_0 datetime2 = '2021-07-21T17:32:31.3980763-06:00';

SELECT  [p].[ParkingLotId], 
        [p].[PriceScheduleId], 
        [p].[EffectiveDate], 
        [p].[ExpiryDate]
FROM [ParkingLotPrice] AS [p]
WHERE (@__currentDate_0 >= [p].[EffectiveDate]) AND (@__currentDate_0 <= [p].[ExpiryDate])
```

Is there a way of keeping the `Where` evaluation, but only declare 1 variable?

Comment: Where is the second sql generated? Can you post it too?

Comment: Added the SQL Query without the null evaluation @Serge

Comment: And what is wrong with it? Does it return a wrong result? I created hundreds queries with null and without and they always return the right result.

Comment: Could you make me a favor, pls? Just because of curiosity can you change the second part of the query  by swapping like this (  x.ExpiryDate == null  ||  (currentDate <= x.ExpiryDate )) and tell me it is still the sql was generated? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @Serge, the query still declaring 2 times

Comment: You cannot control that. This is how current EF Core code extracts parameters from expression tree.

Answer (score 0):

And what is wrong with it? Does it return a wrong result? I created hundreds queries with null and without and they always returned the right result.

I can see the real problem in your query. The way you compare dates. It will compare times too. In some cases it will return a wrong result. I highly recommend you to compare only dates

```
var parkingLotPrice =  _context.ParkingLotPrice
.Where(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.EffectiveDate,currentDate) >=0  
&& (x.ExpiryDate == null || EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(currentDate,x.ExpiryDate)>=0 )).ToList();
```

or if you need some time try this

```
var parkingLotPrice =  _context.ParkingLotPrice
.Where(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(x.EffectiveDate,currentDate) >=0  
&& (x.ExpiryDate == null || EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(currentDate,x.ExpiryDate)>=0 )).ToList();
```

Comment: The results are ok, but my question is why it declare the variable 2 times. And I also need to compare the time too, not only date.

Comment: @AlonsoUreñaq I think you have to send an email to EF team. It is just an algorithm. It doesn't effect any performance, what is the difference for you?